# SharePoint 2016 : User Profile Synchronization Status Idle

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile, error

Need you Urgent Support.

Got stuck in setup of User profile service application in SharePoint 2016. Tried below solutions:

1. All Setup Done.
2. Required Permissions given like Replicating Directory permissions.
3. Tried Service application pool with with Farm Service account.
4. Many time restarted Timer service
5. Also restarted IIS.

I am getting below error in log file:

> "0x18F8 SharePoint Portal Server
>   User Profiles g22d
>   High UserProfileApplication.DumpSynchronizationStatusToFile: Unexpected exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication.DumpSynchronizationStatusToFile()".

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Not getting enough support.

Thanks,

Sunil

Comment: What are you seeing in the ULS logs when you filter on messages with "ILM" in them?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to filter logs with ILM however result was nothing.  also tried new user profile service application however still Status remain same as Idle.

Comment: Did you start the service? Are you using Direct AD Import or FIM?

Comment: Hi Matthew, Yes service is running and i am using AD import method. Not sure what is stopping .

Comment: any progress here? I am stuck on the same error...

Comment: Thanks to all. I am able to resolve the issue.

Comment: SharePoint 2019 On-prem User Profiles not populating from AD. I've created an on-prem SP 2019 installation. Everything seems to be working except the User Profile Synchronization. I start the full import and nothing seems to happen. Profiles are not imported. I get that same error in the ULS log, 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**' Here's the strange part - I open the SharePoint site, and click my name (upper right-hand corner), then 'About me'. SharePoint creates my OneDrive/MySite. THEN my account appears in the Profile! It even has the info from the AD. But running the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make Sure User Profile service application proxy is part of your Default group in service application associations.

Comment: Please let me know if i could help someone.

Comment: Hi Deep I am struck with same issue can you kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure User Profile service application proxy is part of your Default group in service application associations. - Please tell us how we can check this...steps

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/119454)

Comment: Well it actually qualifies as an answer, even though it answers how to associate a new web application with UPSA and not the question OP has.